# Is there any possible way to pickle/serialize a R module imported through rpy2? (Python)

Tags: python, r, serialization, pickle, rpy2

I am working on a package with a dependency on a particular program installed via `R`.  I would rather simplify the installation process and not make the users create a backend for `R` with all of the packages.  This may be completely unavoidable but I'm wondering if there is any possible way to supply the R objects in a serialized form via `pickle` or any serialization module in Python?

I tried `pickle` first and then tried `dill` but had no luck.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> r_package = importr("dynamicTreeCut")
>>> r_package
rpy2.robjects.packages.Package as a <module 'dynamicTreeCut'>
>>> with open("./dynamicTreeCut.rpy2.pkl", "wb") as f:
...     pickle.dump(r_package, f)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: can't pickle InstalledSTPackage objects
```

Comment: Is it an option to install the package into the R instance used by rpy2 from a .gz file?

Comment: So having it install in the backend?

Comment: If by *backend* you mean the embedded R instance used by rpy2 then yes. As far as I understand that should be present on the user's machine if rpy2 is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your suggestion above could be implemented?

Comment: I think your question is not precise enough. Please state more clearly what you want to achieve. It is not entirely clear what you want to inject into R (data or code or ...). Why would it be better to inject this from a .pkl file then from an R package file?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could supply preconfigured packages that are ready to deploy via a pickle object.  Analogous to docker images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need R to use rpy2, and if you wish to use R packages they must be installed with R. How to package R and packages is a question that is relatively independent from rpy2, and detailing the options probably beyond the scope of a SO answer: docker image (see rpy2's own images [with Jupyterlab](https://hub.docker.com/r/rpy2/jupyter/) or [jupyterlab and spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/rpy2/polyglot/)), dedicated installer for precompiled binaries, .deb or .rpm packages, etc...